# Подскажите правильный await, для async метода поиска в БД

Tags: c#, entity-framework, task

Для полноты картины. Имеется БД, содержащая два столбца, созданная по принципу CodeFirst.

Как асинхронно вносить данные и получать все строки из базы - ответ нашёлся, а вот как правильно создавать запросы на выборку - не совсем понятно.

Задача простая - найти в таблице все строки, которые содержат в себе подстроку. В добавок метод должен быть асинхронным. Сделал такой велосипед:

```
private static async Task DbFindAsync(string s)
    {
        using (StringDataContext db = new StringDataContext())
        {
            var cmd = from m in db.Strings where m.Data.Contains(s) select m;
            foreach (StringData sd in cmd)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}. - {1}", sd.Id, sd.Data);
            }
            await db.SaveChangesAsync(); //<< это здесь!
        }
    }
```

Оно дышит и работает, но ***await db.SaveChangesAsync()*** тут смотрится как седло на корове.

Как правильно переделать этот метод, или в какую сторону копать?

Comment: а что не так с `await db.SaveChangesAsync()`?

Comment: @Grundy что-то мне подсказывает что это попахивает. Хочется спросить совета у опытных разработчиков

Comment: Чем же? Что подсказывает?

Comment: Хотя вообще непонятно, что делает твой метод?

Comment: @Grundy ну, например для выборки всех строк из таблицы использовался: await db.strings.ForEachAsync() и он смотрелся на своём месте

Comment: Он находит все строки в БД, которые содержат определённую подстроку и выводит в консоль

Answer (score 6, accepted):

До тех пор пока в C# нет оператора асинхронного перечисления, правильным решением будет асинхронная материализация результата запроса в List:

```
var cmd = from m in db.Strings where m.Data.Contains(s) select m;
foreach (StringData sd in await cmd.ToListAsync())
{
    // ...
}
```

Также не забудьте отключить ленивую загрузку навигационных свойств, потому что сделать ее асинхронно невозможно.

Возможно, после принятия предложения [Async Streams](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/43) командой разработки языка C# новая версия EF будет поддерживать более красивый вариант.